# Connect to Azure VM by RDP: An internal error has occurred

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, rdp, internals

we have the virtual machine:
account: xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx,
account type: Personal account,
subscription: Microsoft Partner Network,
resource group: xxxxxxxxxxx,
virtual machine: xxxxxxxxxxx,
public ip address: xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx and
OS: Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.

I downloaded the xxxxxxxxxxx.rdp from Azure portal.

If I clicked on the RDP I had got error:
Remote Desktop Connection: An internal error has occurred.

Do you know cause?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my issue with these 3 steps. To do so, you need to be able to connect to your machine with RDP. I can do that, if I am connecting while it is starting up, then my RDP somehow works.

The permanent fix for me was these steps.

1: remove the checkmark

[image: remove check mark]

2: change group policy setting

[image: change group policy]

3: delete machine keys

[image: delete machine keys]

Comment: I used FreeRDP (mentioned in one of the other answers here) then after following these steps I was able to connect using the default Windows RDP client.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an alternative RDP client, such as the [Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps) Windows Store app or even [FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/PreBuilds).

Edit to add: RDP access had been misconfigured leaving open access to the public internet and there were multiple dead connections leftover from brute force attempts to login. Cleaning up the firewall to restrict access meant no more invalid login attempts and the problem seems to have gone away without any VM configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

The internal error may be caused by several reasons and you can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-internal-error) to troubleshoot and solve it. Take care, backup the VM OS disk is an important action and should be done before doing other actions.

Comment: Hi Charles, the document, on whom you referred I read, but my problem did not resolve. Thanks.

Comment: @Laco Did you do all the steps?

Comment: yes. Support from Microsoft advised to me redeploy VM, I will try it.

Comment: @Laco The steps all contain it. Redeploy the VM is the final way.